# Probability an experiment takes 5 trials to succeed?

Tags: probability

Assume the outcome of an experiment can either fail or succeed.
The probability to succeed is 1/3. Let X be the number of times that
the experiment is performed until three successes has been obtained.
What is the probability that X = 5?

What I did:

$$
{5 \choose 3}\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac23\right)^2 \approx .16
$$

I know the correct answer is 0.0987. What did I do wrong?

Comment: you should have that in the first 4 experiments there are 2 successes and the fifth experiment is a success.

Comment: The word "until" makes your answer wrong (i.e., by selecting $3$ out of $5$ you are also counting cases where success has been obtained after $3$ or $4$ attempts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have computed is the probability that you obtain $3$ successes after $5$ trials. But those successes may be attained *before* the fifth trial.

The probability is
$$\begin{align}
P(&\text{2 successes in the first $4$ trials})\cdot P(\text{success in the fifth trial})=\\
&=\binom42\left(\frac13\right)^2\left(\frac23\right)^2\left(\frac13\right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You want ${4\choose 2}\left(\frac 1 3\right)^{3}\left(\frac 2 3\right)^{2}=\frac{8}{81}$

Reason: The favoured situation is 2 successes and 2 failures in any order and then the third success.  The third success needs to be on the fifth trial.

What you calculated was just 3 successes and 2 failures in any order.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is wrong because it takes into consideration those cases where the experiment completes successfully $3$ times after **at most** $5$ attempts (by multiplying with $\binom53=10$):

1. $00111$ - the experiment completes successfully after $5$ attempts
2. $01011$ - the experiment completes successfully after $5$ attempts
3. $01101$ - the experiment completes successfully after $5$ attempts
4. $01110$ - the experiment completes successfully after $4$ attempts
5. $10011$ - the experiment completes successfully after $5$ attempts
6. $10101$ - the experiment completes successfully after $5$ attempts
7. $10110$ - the experiment completes successfully after $4$ attempts
8. $11001$ - the experiment completes successfully after $5$ attempts
9. $11010$ - the experiment completes successfully after $4$ attempts
10. $11100$ - the experiment completes successfully after $3$ attempts

In order for the answer to be correct, you need to count only those $6$ cases where the experiment completes successfully $3$ times after **exactly** $5$ attempts (i.e., by multiplying with $6$ instead of $10$).